# Adding Facebook Fan Page to New App

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Under Apps > Settings > Advanced, there is a spot to add an App Page. I already have an App Page built for my app, but this only allows you to create a new one. Is there any way to connect my existing App Page with this App? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using existing Page as App page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9791279/using-existing-page-as-app-page)

Answer (score 0):

No you Can't use an existing FB page as app page, even you use page as application page facebook not consider as application default page and you not get go to app. page Button..